# Sugarcrm, writing custom code while saving the record

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I am customizing the SugarCRM. At some point I need to store some custom values to the database while user creates the record. I tried to use Triggers, but it didn't fulfill the requirement. So I need to write that in PHP code.

My question is, where to write this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use logic hooks (after_save or before_save e.g.) on the module's save action.

- Create a logic_hooks.php in custom/modules/*myModule*/

  ```
  <?
  $hook_array = Array(); 
  $hook_array['after_save'] = Array(); 
  $hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(
      0,
      'myName',
      'custom/modules/myModule/logic_hooks/file.php',
      'myClass',
      'myMethod'
  );
  ?>
  ```
- Create file.php in /custom/modules/*myModule*/logic_hooks/

  ```
  <?php
  class myClass{
      function myMethod(&$bean, $event, $arguments){
          // Do something with $bean (e.g. store the custom DB value)
      }
  }
  ?>
  ```

For more info see: [this link](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9003336).

Comment: I tried like this, it automatically loads, logic_hooks.php while saving, but its not calling the myMethod function. I have given the correct path but stored in /custom/modules/CV_Customer_Visits folder

Comment: I think it should be a relative path, so `/custom/modules/CV_Customer_Visits/your_php_file.php` should properly by `custom/modules/CV_Customer_Visits/your_php_file.php`

Comment: I wonder, There are some code for feeds defined in sugar which is used these hook methods. When I write my code in that file with a new function it is executing correctly. However, when I change the location of the same file it is not working (I changed the corresponding path in hook calling also)

Comment: Could you post the contents of your files and their filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your_php_file.php is executable by apache.  It could be that or possibly a misspelling?  See if there is anything in your apache log files.