# How to create Hooks in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created two fields in a module assigned date and reviewed date. I want review date must be 7 days after the assigned date. Please  anyone help me and send me the code how to do that as I'm very new to the sugar.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the PRO or higher edition of sugar, you should be able to create it with workflow management.

For CE edition (and the other editions as well) you can create it using logic hooks. You properly need an `after_save` logic hook on the given module.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7977036/344951) for a description on how to create a logic hook.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://technossips.com/how-to/computer/how-to-create-logic-hooks-in-sugar-crm/) is very detailed explanation of how you can create logic hooks in SugarCRM